# Serving static index.html in django

Tags: python, angularjs, django, cordova, meanjs

Thing is, I have an angular + cordova app on one module. I just want the REST api from django for the webserver. no views or anything (well only to serve the angular views).

How can I serve the static index.html using django? do I need different project structure? I'm a newbie to django.

Thanks in advance!

[image: This is driving me nuts.]

Comment: Is it possible for you to put this index.html page in your server/templates folder? Edit: By the way, for REST api, it's better to not return HTML pages (return JSON objects instead). So just to verify, you want your REST api to serve an html page?

Comment: Yes. the same one I use in my cordova app (index.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `TemplateView` directly:

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

...
url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html'))
```

Remember you need to [configure your templates folder](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#template-dirs) to call `.html` files by name only.

Comment: Ok new question mate. all of my assets (CSS/JS etc...) are sitting in `app/www...` and django is unable to find them. how do I use staticfiles to overcome this?

Comment: Here you will find the config you need in that case: [statics files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#static-files). Note the example using full path.

Comment: sadly i tried `STATIC_URL = '/app/www/'` and `STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    "/app/www",
)` but none worked

Comment: Is that your full path?

Comment: I also tried this: `STATIC_URL = 'G:/Desktop/GetSocial/app/www/'`. didn't work.

Comment: How are you loading static files in template? You should post a new question with more details about this.

Answer (score 0):

First, place this index.html page in your server/templates folder so Django knows about it.

Then, do this in your URLs.py:

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html')),
]
```